# Conditional cumsum / floor value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm trying to use floor and ceiling values in cumsum. Whenever uniqueEntry has a positive value, Positions are incremented and whenever uniqueExit is positive, Positions is reduced. Yet Positions should have floor value of 0 and ceiling of 3.

Secondly, for each Symbol, if uniqueEntry is triggered when Positions is at ceiling value, both uniqueEntry and uniqueExit (per Symbol) are ignored in Positions calculation until uniqueEntry is triggered when Positions is below ceiling value. Desired results in the final example.

In practice, I'm looking at stock positions, limiting the number of positions to a value and excluding the rest. Is this possible without looping?

Test data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

np.random.seed(56)
symbols, symlen = 2, 3

times =             np.arange(datetime(2021, 1, 5), datetime(2021, 1, 12), timedelta(days=1)).astype(np.datetime64)
tlen =              len(times)
A, Z =              np.array(['A', 'Z']).view('int32')
symbol_names =      np.random.randint(low=A, high=Z, size=symbols * symlen, dtype='int32').view(f'U{symlen}')
limit =             np.random.randint(low=0, high=5, size=symbols*tlen, dtype='int32')
reset =             np.random.randint(low=-1, high=1, size=symbols*tlen, dtype='int32')
times =             np.concatenate([times] * symbols)
names =             np.array([y for x in [[s] * tlen for s in symbol_names] for y in x])
value_col =         np.random.randint(low=30, high=60, size=len(times), dtype='uint32')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Values': value_col}, index=[times, names])
df.index = df.index.set_names(['Date', 'Symbol'])
```

Create columns that determine conditions:

```
df['uniqueEntry'] = np.where(df.Values > 45, 1, 0)
df['uniqueExit'] = np.where(df.Values < 40, 1, 0)
```

Sort and cumsum:

```
df = df.sort_index(level='Date')
df['Positions'] = (df.uniqueEntry - df.uniqueExit).cumsum()
```

Current result:

```
df

                    Values  uniqueEntry     uniqueExit  Positions
Date        Symbol              
2021-01-05  ACL     42      0               0           0
            VEP     40      0               0           0
2021-01-06  ACL     30      0               1           -1
            VEP     31      0               1           -2
2021-01-07  ACL     38      0               1           -3
            VEP     46      1               0           -2
2021-01-08  ACL     59      1               0           -1
            VEP     43      0               0           -1
2021-01-09  ACL     52      1               0           0
            VEP     50      1               0           1
2021-01-10  ACL     34      0               1           0
            VEP     36      0               1           -1
2021-01-11  ACL     44      0               0           -1
            VEP     48      1               0           0
```

Desired results:

```
                    Values  uniqueEntry     uniqueExit  Positions
Date        Symbol              
2021-01-05  ACL     42      0               0           0
            VEP     40      0               0           0
2021-01-06  ACL     30      0               1           0
            VEP     31      0               1           0
2021-01-07  ACL     38      0               1           0
            VEP     46      1               0           1
2021-01-08  ACL     59      1               0           2
            VEP     43      0               0           2
2021-01-09  ACL     52      1               0           3
            VEP     50      1               0           3 <- should be excluded
2021-01-10  ACL     34      0               1           2
            VEP     36      0               1           2 <- should be ignored as uniqueEntry triggered while Positions = 3
2021-01-11  ACL     44      0               0           1
            VEP     48      1               0           2
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible without using a for loop, since the value of Positions relies on the previous value. You might be able to find some way by doing some fancy manipulations/function calls, but what's wrong with just doing `df.iterrows()`?

Comment: Speed. But I'm looking into looping but using itertuples() as it's significantly faster or using numba. Looping is the exponentially simpler solution here clearly.